# what is the difference between the two datasets for numpy.fft

Tags: python, numpy, signals, fft

I am trying to find the period of a sin curve and can find the right periods for `sin(t)`.
However for `sin(k*t)`, the frequency shifts. I do not know how it shifts.
I can adjust the value of `interd` below to get the right signal only if I know the dataset is `sin(0.6*t)`.

Why can I get the right result for `sin(t)`?
Anyone can detect the right signal just based on my code ? Or just a small change?

The figure below is the power spectral density of `sin(0.6*t)`.
The dataset is like:

```
1,sin(1*0.6)
2,sin(2*0.6)
3,sin(3*0.6)
.........
2000,sin(2000*0.6)
```

And my code:

```
timepoints = np.loadtxt('dataset', usecols=(0,), unpack=True, delimiter=",")
intensity = np.loadtxt('dataset', usecols=(1,), unpack=True, delimiter=",")
binshu = 300
lastime = 2000
interd = 2000.0/300 
sp = np.fft.fft(intensity)
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(intensity),d=interd) 
freqnum = np.fft.fftfreq(len(intensity),d=interd).argsort()
pl.xlabel("frequency(Hz)")
pl.plot(freq[freqnum]*6.28, np.sqrt(sp.real**2+sp.imag**2)[freqnum])
```

[image: fig]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're making it too complicated.  If you consider `timepoints` to be in *seconds* then `interd` is `1` (difference between values in `timepoints`).  This works fine for me:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

# you can do this in one line, that's what 'unpack' is for:
timepoints, intensity = np.loadtxt('dataset', usecols=(0,1), unpack=True, delimiter=",")

interd = timepoints[1] - timepoints[0] # if this is 1, it can be ignored
sp = np.fft.fft(intensity)
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(intensity), d=interd)

pl.plot(np.fft.fftshift(freq), np.fft.fftshift(np.abs(sp)))
pl.xlabel("frequency(Hz)")
pl.show()
```

You'll also note that I didn't sort the frequencies, that's what `fftshift` is for.

Also, don't do `np.sqrt(sp.imag**2 + sp.real**2)`, that's what `np.abs` is for :)

[image: simpler]

If you're not sampling enough (the frequency is higher than your sample rate, i.e., `2*pi/interd < 0.5*k`), then there's no way for `fft` to know how much data you're missing, so it assumes you're not missing any. You can't expect it to know a priori. This is the data you're giving it:

[image: input waves]

Comment: That works fine for `sin(0.6*t)`. But if you use the default d=1, there are two problems.The frequency range is limited to [-0.5,0.5]. And you may get the wrong peak for `sin(6*t)`.

Comment: For the high frequency, that's not a problem with the `fft`... plot your signal first and you'll see that if you take `np.sin(6*t)` where `t = np.arange(1,2001)` that you're not seeing a signal with frequency `6`.  `fft` can only tell you what you give it.  If you do have advanced knowledge that you're undersampling the signal, you can correct for this but without that knowledge, it's impossible to determine, which is what I believe you're asking for.

Comment: You're welcome :)  For more information, take a look at [Nyquist Rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate).  In short, you cannot detect any frequency more than half your sampling frequency, instead you'll detect some other frequency.  Here, your sampling frequency `f = 1 Hz` or `w = 2 pi rad/sec`, so the fastest frequency you can detect will be `pi rad/sec` which is lower than the input frequency for `sin(6*t)`.

Comment: Or more specifically, if k is always an integer, then sin(6*k)=sin((6-2*pi)*k), and 6-2*pi is around -0.2832, so this will be the frequency you see, that is, the sampled sequence is the one of -sin(0.2832*k).

Comment: Hm, I must have used it to make the second plot, but I didn't use it to find the frequency because the spacing is `1`. Technically, I should have used `fftfreq(len(intensity), d=timesteps[1] - timesteps[0])`. But in this case that difference is `1`, which is the default.